# Enforce CORS checks in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

I have a REST API and a JS SDK that consumes it. The SDK is meant primarily for browsers and can consume the API from any origin (the API server has the appropriate CORS settings).

I have tests that use the JS SDK to validate certain flows in the server-side API. The tests are run in Node.js.

The problem with that is Node.js does not care about CORS, meaning that I could deploy a version of the API server with a broken CORS configuration and the tests would give no indication that the service is broken for the vast majority of users (who are consuming the SDK in the browser).

Is there a way to enforce CORS checks in Node.js (i.e., instruct Node to do networking *as though* it is running in a browser)? The solution would preferably require very little changes to the existing SDK code.

If this is not possible, are there any other approaches I should consider? So far the only alternative I can think of is doing the OPTIONS request manually and doing assertions on the returned CORS headers.

Comment: What HTTP client are you using in your SDK? Have you considered sending an `OPTIONS` message by yourself and checking the response?

Comment: I have considered this, yes. Why I'm looking for alternatives is that this still leaves open the possibility that I'm doing the manual check incorrectly. 
In the end I'm interested in verifying that the tests pass in _a_ browser (1 is enough), so I'm looking for a solution that would as end-to-end as possible.